# Segmentation Fault: Dynamically allocating matrix using a double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation, sizeof

Trying to understand the usage and memory allocation of double pointers in C.

Below is my code: -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    
    printf("Enter rows and columns respectively: -\n");
    
    int rows, columns;
    scanf("%d%d", &rows, &columns);
    
    int **matrix;
    
    matrix = calloc(rows, sizeof(int));
    
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = calloc(columns, sizeof(int));
    }
    
    printf("Enter your elements\n");
    
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    printf("Your elements are: -\n");
    
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    free(matrix);
    
    return 0;
}
```

After getting `Segmentation fault: 11`, I searched on the net and found out that instead of writing this: -

```
int **matrix;
matrix = calloc(rows, sizeof(int));
```

I should write: -

```
int **matrix;
matrix = calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));
```

After making the above changes, my code works fine.

***My question is: -***

> 1. What is the difference between sizeof(int) and sizeof(int *)?
> 2. Don't both of them allocate 4 bytes? (int occupies 4 bytes and int*
>    (which is noting but a pointer) also occupies 4 bytes?
> 3. If both of them allocates the same space, then why was I getting a
>    Segmentation fault in the first case?

Comment: Pointers are not always 4 bytes. They are 8 bytes in 64 bit binaries. Just print out `sizeof(int *)` to see for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Don't both of them allocate 4 bytes? (int occupies 4 bytes and int* (which is noting but a pointer) also occupies 4 bytes?

What makes you think that a pointer is four bytes? On most modern (64 bit) architectures, pointers to object are 8 bytes, not 4.

Hence, in general `sizeof(int) ≠ sizeof(int *)`. But you can’t make many assumptions about the sizes of objects in portable C code, and you definitely can’t assume that `sizeof(int) == 4`, or `sizeof(int*) == 8` (nor `4`). Depending on the platform, these sizes vary. They *could* also have the same size. You just can’t assume that.

To avoid confusion between pointer and pointee size, some people (me included) recommend using the *object name* in the `sizeof` expression in allocations, rather than the type name:

```
int **matrix = calloc(rows, sizeof *matrix);
// …
matrix[i] = calloc(columns, sizeof **matrix);
```

This makes it clear *what* you are trying to allocate. Note that `sizeof expr` does not *evaluate* `expr`; this is important, since the expressions `*matrix` and `**matrix` are *invalid* before you’ve allocated the memory — deferencing the unassigned pointer would be undefined behaviour. But `sizeof` only determines the object size of the expression without actually evaluating it.

Comment: It would be good to add that both `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(int *) == 8` (and definitely `sizeof(int *) == 4`) are wrong assumptions _in general_ because the C standard doesn't specify the size of most types.

Comment: How does `sizeof` determine the object size of the expression without evaluating it?

Comment: @SwarnimKhosla: the `sizeof` operator is evaluated at compile time unless its operand is a VLA. The compiler knows what `sizeof(*x)` should be at compile time because it is aware of what type `*x` has.

Comment: @Peter my teacher in college taught us that `pointer size` and `int size` are the same. Maybe he meant `32 bit` systems?